# 401 Mysterious unauthorized

Tags: post, request, axios

Hello fellow programmers,

I've got the following problem. I do a post request with axios as shown below:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const config = {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${Auth.getToken()}` },
    };
    const urlCategories = "http://localhost:8090/category";
    axios.get(urlCategories, config).then((res) => {
      const categories = res.data;
      this.setState({ categories });
      console.log(this.state.categories);
    });
    const urlTricks = "http://localhost:8090/trick/" + Auth.parseJwt().sub;
    axios.get(urlTricks, config).then((res) => {
      const tricks = res.data;
      this.setState({ tricks });
      console.log(this.state.tricks);
    });
  }
```

This works! :D

Then I want to do the same but later, so I almost copied this BUT...
I get a 401 while I can't see any real difference between the two. I even asked my teacher and he didn't know the answer to it.

```
handleChecked = () => {
    if (this.state.learned) {
      this.setState(
        {
          learned: false,
        },
        () => {
          console.log("Should be false and is: " + this.state.learned);
          const config = {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${Auth.getToken()}` },
          };
          axios
            .post(
              "http://localhost:8090/user/" +
                Auth.parseJwt().sub +
                "/" +
                this.props.id +
                "/" +
                this.state.learned,
              config
            )
            .then(() => {
              console.log(this.props.name + " set to: " + this.state.learned);
            });
        }
      );
    } else { }
```

The weird thing is; it works in Postman so my conclusion is there must be something wrong with the front-end. Back-end should be okay. If you're curious: Auth.parseJwt().sub gets the username (I know it's a weird name for a username). Another weird thing is when I copy the URL in the Chrome Inspect overview and use it in Postman, it works...

Does anyone know or see what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

My name is Appeltaart and if it works in postman, the back-end should be fine just as you said.  You can start your application from scratch or try this :D

```js
axios.post(`http://localhost:8090/user/${Auth.parseJwt().sub}/${this.props.id}/${this.state.learned}`, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${Auth.getToken()}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }).then(() => {
        console.log(this.props.name + " set to: " + this.state.learned);
    });
```

Friendly Greetings,
Your Applepie

Comment: Thank you for your answer Appeltaart. Unfortunately, this didn't fix it. I'm still stuck at this part. My application is finished :) but only this part isn't working yet...

Comment: So what you gonna do about it? :(

Comment: I didn't fix it, but already had my school assessment a cpuple of days ago, including this bug :') But it was fine, my teacher saw the code and had a feeling that I understood it. But thanks for your input Appeltaart. I appreciate that! :)

Comment: Aah good to hear that you passed! No probs bro, you are the best!